# Найти все триггеры базы данных

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Необходимо найти все триггеры, родителем которых является БД.
Думал выполню скрипт ниже и будет мне счастье, но нет

```
select *
from [sys].[triggers]
where [parent_class_desc] = 'DATABASE'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить все триггеры которые висят на указанной БД.

Comment: вас какие триггеры интересуют, вообще все что существует в БД? или обычные insert-update-delete триггеры к таблицам этой БД?

Comment: Те что относятся к уровню бд

Answer (score 3):

Ваш запрос вернёт информацию о DDL-триггерах (если они, конечно, есть в БД).

Чтобы найти DML-триггеры фильтруйте по `parent_class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'`

```
select
    schemaName = s.name,
    objectName = o.name,
    triggerName = tr.name
from
    sys.triggers tr
    join sys.objects o on o.object_id = tr.parent_id
    join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
where
    tr.parent_class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
order by
    s.name, o.name, tr.name
```

Comment: Не особо помню тему, но разве недостаточно просто искать записи с parent_class = 0 или 1 ? ну вот например в доках: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2014/ms188746(v=sql.120)

Comment: @AK, достаточно, но parent_class_desc читабельнее (на мой взгляд), вдруг этот же код будет кто-то читать после меня, это хорошо здесь две константы (0 и 1) - можно запомнить, а если какой-нибудь `type` в [sys.indexes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql).

Comment: Мысль понял, спасибо за пояснения.

Answer (score 1):

Системные таблицы для каждой базы данных свои. Поэтому нужно сначала выбрать БД:

```
use database
select name from sys.triggers;
```

Comment: Коллега, формально вроде как и ответ (привет из очереди проверки), но я бы рекомендовал пояснить словами ваш код, он мало чем отличается от приведённого в запросе. Хотя я не уверен ещё, что топикстартер точно понимает чего именно он хочет в запросе видеть.

Comment: Пояснил + 4 символа.

Comment: Скажем так, у меня на уровне баз (5 шт.) висят ddl триггеры, мне необходимо получить все эти триггеры , и увидеть какие из них включены, а какие нет. В sys.triggers видно, что они на базе, видно, что он вкл или выкл, но не видно какая бд.

Comment: @idrees дак БД - текущая выбранная. Вам нужно триггеры со всех баз собрать?

Comment: @teran необходимо выбрать ddl триггеры со всех доступных баз. либо указанной базы без использования use

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку `sys.triggers` у каждой базы свой, а вам нужны триггеры со всех баз на сервере, то как вариант, можно сначала пройтись по всем базам и все записи о триггерах впихать во временную таблицу. Тут собственно, либо составить через `union` динамический sql запрос, либо выполнить запрос с помощью недокументированной `sp_MSForEachDB`.

Возможно есть пути и проще, но за неимением других ответов:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);


IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tdata') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #tdata;

CREATE TABLE #tdata (dbname varchar(255), trname varchar(255));

SELECT @sql = STUFF(
             (SELECT  char(10) + 'UNION' + char(10)+ ' select ''' + name + ''' as dbname, name  COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS as trname from [' + name  + '].sys.triggers' 
              FROM master.sys.databases 
              WHERE state = 0           -- базы, которые онлайн
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 6, '')




SET @sql = 'insert into #tdata ' + @sql;
--PRINT @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql;


SELECT * from #tdata;

DROP TABLE #tdata;
```

К сожалению, структуру временной таблицы приходится описывать, т.к. `select * into` не будет работать из-за ограничений области видимости.

Поскольку базы могут быт созданы с разным COLLATION, то приходится явно указывать `collate` при выборке, хотя может обойдетесь и без.

с `sp_MSForEachDB` проще будет, но я про нее вспомнил когда уже написал остальной запрос.

если же вы заведомо знаете имя БД, то не надо опрашивать все базы, просто изначально сформировать запрос на выборку из `@dbname + '.sys.triggers'`